# Open square in open disk

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to show that in any open disk $B_\delta(y) \subset \Bbb R^2$ and around any point $x ∈ B_\delta(y)$ there is always room for an open square centred around $x$ that lies completely within the disk. Let's call this square $(a,b)×(c,d)$. I've played around with this for a few hours now, but both solutions invoking trigonometry and solutions involving $d(x, y)$ and $\delta$ have come up empty.

Anyone know another way to do this? That is, to express $a,b,c,d$ in terms of $y$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Find an open ball centered at $x$ inside $B_{\delta}(y)$ first. Then find an open square inside that ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly indirect approach:

First, let's show it for $x=y$. Say $y=(y_1,y_2)$. Consider the square
$$U=(y_1-r,y_1+r)\times(y_2-r,y_2+r),$$
where $r>0$ is to be determined later. Fix $z=(z_1,z_2)\in U$. Then
$$
\|y-z\|=\sqrt{(y_1-z_1)^2+(y_2-z_2)^2}\le \sqrt{r^2+r^2}=\sqrt{2}r
$$
Taking $r<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}$, we get that $z\in B_\delta(y)$, so $U\subset B_\delta(y)$.

In the general case, fix $x\in B_\delta(y)$. Find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subset B_\delta(y)$. Now apply the preceding argument to the ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$.